# Limit of a function with restricted domain

Tags: calculus

Given  a  function $f(x)$ whose domain is $\left[-4,6\right]$, is it possible to find $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 6^+} f(x)?$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of $\lim_{x \to 6+} f(x)$ requires $f(x)$ to be defined for $x$ in some interval to the right of $6$.  If that is not the case, then  $\lim_{x \to 6+} f(x)$ does not exist.